# MatchQ strange behavior

Tags: pattern-matching

While checking for a pattern I came across this test:

```
MatchQ[-A.Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1],k], ___.Grad[Subscript[f, x_,x_],_]]
```

which returns `False`. However, if I remove the extra minus as

```
MatchQ[A.Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1],k], ___.Grad[Subscript[f, x_,x_],_]]
```

then it returns `True`. How should I change the pattern `___.Grad[Subscript[f, x_,x_],_]` to also include the minus sign?

Comment: `MatchQ[-A . Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1], k], 
 Grad[Subscript[f, x_, x_], _] | 
  Times[_, Dot[_, Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1], k]]]
 ]` ??

Comment: It's a matter of operator precedence; infix Dot binds more tightly even than unary minus. So this variant works: `In[22]:= MatchQ[(-A) . Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1], k], ___ . 
  Grad[Subscript[f, x_, x_], _]]

Out[22]= True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching is done purely structurally. Therefore, look at the FullForm of your expressions:

```
-A . Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1], k] // FullForm
A . Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1], k] // FullForm
```

[image]

[image]

Now look at the full form of your pattern:

```
___ . Grad[Subscript[f, x_, x_], _] // FullForm
```

[image]

Now you see that only the second pattern matches.

Answer (score 1):

To answer *"How should I change the pattern ***.Grad[Subscript[f, x*,x*],*] to also include the minus sign?"*

```
MatchQ[
    -A . Grad[Subscript[f, 1, 1], k]
    , With[
        {
            b=Dot[A,Grad[Subscript[f, x_, x_], _]]
        }
        , Alternatives[b, Times[_, b]]
    ]
]
(* True *)
```